# How to work around 'lastindexof' is a primitive and doesn't support nested properties in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to take an existing filename in data factory and using dynamic content rearrange it so it has a timestamp appended to it. However I seem to be getting the following error:

> Position 172 'lastindexof' is a primitive and doesn't support nested properties.

It seems I can't put calculations within arguments to other functions which is really restrictive. Is there any work around for this? Should I be looking at another component in Data Factory to achieve this more easily?

Please see the dynamic content expression below:

`@concat(substring(item().name, 0, lastindexof(item().name, '.')), '_', formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'), '.', substring(item().name, lastindexof(item().name, '.') + 1, length(item().name) - lastindexof(item().name, '.') - 1))`

A basic test of what I want to achieve is to take the input filename `abc.csv` or `xyz.xlsx` and convert this to `abc_20200213131301.csv` or `xyz_20200213131301.xlsx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing which you are trying will work , i have done that but there will be too many "(" and ","

You can try implement by using 2 Set variables activity & Split function  .

1st Activity

to use the split function with : @split(variables('FileName'),'.')

2nd Activity

@concat(variables('SplitFileName')[0],'_',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'),'.',variables('SplitFileName')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTcM8.gif))

[image]

Comment: This solution works assuming that there are no `.` in the filename. Would be good to see if it could be more resilient and adapted to work when we have a file name of `ab.c.csv` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

```
@concat(substring(item().name,0,lastindexof(item().name,'.')),'_',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'), replace(item().name,substring(item().name,0,lastindexof(item().name,'.')),''))
```

Another option is to use `add` or `sub` functions. To find the remaining characters after the last ".", I used the `sub` function.

```
@concat(substring(item().name,0,lastindexof(item().name,'.')),'_',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'), substring(item().name, lastindexof(item().name,'.'), sub(length(item().name), lastindexof(item().name, '.'))))
```

Comment: Yes I found out about using the add and sub functions in place of the + and - operators about a month after raising this. Its very useful info so thanks for posting